# echo returning null from database table

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am making a restapi using android,php,mysql and json.
but got stuck in the small php script .
I have rows in my table but echo shows them null.
please help.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sms");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query="SELECT * FROM messages";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$noofrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$temp_array=array();
if($noofrows>0) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
    {               
        echo $row['Name']." ".$row['Gender'];
        echo $row;          
        $temp_array[]=$row;                     
    }
}   
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("usersms"=>$temp_array));
mysqli_close($con);                             
?>
```

Comment: jason response  usersms shows null.. The echo in while shows nothing.

Comment: moreover when i echo $noofrows it shows me the exact no. of rows in my database..

Comment: Did that fix it? Was it the semicolon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks right, it may be the semicolon here closing the while statement:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
```

which should be

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
```

Comment: No problem. If you could accept my answer, that would be great.